# How to fold all occurrences of a regex in vim?

Tags: regex, vim, folding

A colleague of mine is using a horrible source code editor that leaves strange comments all over the code. In Visual Studio, I [created a macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656275/how-to-auto-collapse-certain-comments-in-visual-studio-2010), that simply folds all those comment blocks so I don't have to see them.

Now I would like to do the very same thing in vim.

This regex matches every one of those blocks:

```
/^.*\/\* EasyCODE.*\(\(\n.*\*\/\)\|\(\n.*\/\*.*\)\|\(\n\/\/.*\)\)*/
```

Now I bet there is a really nice way to fold all matches of this pattern in vim. However, I am rather new to vim and don't know how to do this.

Could you help me there?

**Edit:** some examples:

These comment blocks always begin with `/* EasyCODE`. Sometimes the comment have a closing `*/` right on the end of the first line, sometimes only on the next line. The following lines might or might not contain additional "`/* EasyCODE`..." blocks.

One of these blocks could look like this

```
/* EasyCODE ) */
/* EasyCODE ( 0 
some text */
/* EasyCODE F */
```

or like this

```
/* EasyCODE V8 */
/* EasyCODE ( 0 */
```

or like this

```
/* EasyCODE > */
```

As I said, the above regex catches them all.

Comment: Can you give an example of what the blocks look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not completely clear on the details of your blocks (hence the comment about providing an example), but you could use something like this:

```
:set foldmarker=/\*\ EasyCODE,\*/
:set foldmethod=marker
```

This will configure the 'marker' fold method that looks for certain markers in the code and then it will set the starting marker to `/* EasyCODE` and the ending marker to `*/`.  Hopefully this will give you something to get you started.  If you could post a sample source file, I may be able to offer some more advice.

```
:help folding
:help 'foldmarker'
:help 'foldmethod'
:help fold-marker
```

Comment: The answer is correct but one important thing is that the `foldmarker` entries are literal strings and not regexs.